# Showing error in google signin is not working in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, backend

```
  @override
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    final googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (googleUser != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth
            .signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        ));
        return userCredential.user;
      } else {
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
            code: "ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN",
            message: "Missing Google ID Token");
      }
    } else {
      throw FirebaseAuthException(
        code: "ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER",
        message: "Sign in aborted by user",
      );
    }
  }
```

// Google Signin is not working in flutter and showing error The service for com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zbe is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
I/flutter ( 2970): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: , null, null)[1]

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue. On the emulator it works but on a real device it doesn't, were you able to figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any updates on how to solve this issue?

Comment: If you guys use custom ROM then it can be issue. See this post - https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/mjoez6/anyone_facing_problem_to_login_with_google_in/